# Dynamically switching from component to tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Is it possible in Vue to switch between component and tag, like we can switch between components?

```
<component :is="component"></component>
```

My case: I want a button component to be wrapped with `router-link` tag if a path was specified, and if there is no path it would be a simple `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a computed property "component" and handle which tag should be used

```
computed:{
    component(){
        if(// has path)
            return RouterLink;
        else
            return 'div';
    }
}
```